# Why isn't the sound volume tied to decibels

Tags: volume, decibel, soundcard

Why isn't the sound volume of a device tied to decibels? And could you deduct the decibels from the source of the sound and the volume, or at least the percentual difference of decibels between two moments?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the correct place to answer this question

Comment: When I run `alsamixer` on my linux box it shows the volume as attenuation from full volume in dB. What are you trying to do? Are you writing a program that will do things like "reduce volume 3dB"? Otherwise, and unless you specify OS and language, this is well off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Decibels is a unit of measure for the amplitude of a sound wave, it's also used for the SPL(sound pressure level) of a sound wave. It is a measurement of the sound waves passing through the air, not the output of the device at any given time.  If you ever see a `dB` rating on a device or speaker, that is just a notation of what the device is capable of. That output value will always vary based on local conditions, speaker type, amplifier type and many other factors.  Even humidity.

So with that said, manufactures could not place a `dB` rating for when you are changing a *volume* on a device.  **Theoretically, the volume setting of a device and the SPL of a sound wave, are not related at all.**